# SQLAlchemy automap does not work for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, orm, pyodbc

I just noticed that `automap` does not work for `SQL Server` to me.

```
Base = automap_base()

params = quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
                            f"SERVER={self.server},{self.port};" 
                            f"DATABASE={self.db_name};"
                            f"UID={self.user};"
                            f"PWD={self.password}")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

session: Session = Session(bind=engine)
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

**AFTER**

When I try this:

```
list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable"))
```

it returns real rows so `mytable` exists for sure, the connection is alive and there are rows

But `list(Base.classes)` returns `[]`

How is that possible and is there a way to make it work? As my code relies on `automap_base`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/Kgu0zhJb) works fine for me.

Comment: Do you get any warnings output when executing `Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)`? Have you tried specifying a particular schema? e.g.: `Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, schema='dbo')` and `list(session.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable"))`